# Average Multiple Runs (5 Runs) of The Sample & Graph it

Tags: python-2.7, graph, plotly

I have five cvs files containing two columns corresponding to Diameter and Intensity of a sample to each run. Each file corresponds to a single run of the sample, and the values of those columns might be slightly different from the runs, but will be close to each other.

Sample of run from the csv file:

```
Diameter,Intensity
3.00e+1,0.00
3.19e+1,0.00
3.39e+1,0.00
3.60e+1,0.00
3.83e+1,0.00
4.08e+1,7.01
```

My goal is to draw a scatter plot diagram using Python to read in those five cvs files and generate a single scatter curve line averaging the five runs into a single averaged curve one? How can that be done?

Here is my attempt in coding using Plotly. The problem with the following code is that the curve is not drawing correctly when averaging the intensities of the five runs:

```
files = defaultdict(list)
file_start = raw_input("File Starts: ")

def read_data(file):
 with open(file,'Ur') as f:
  reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
  for row in reader:
  if "d (nm)" in row:
   continue
  else:
    files[file].append(row)


os.chdir(".")           
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
 if file_start in file: 
  read_data(file)

for key, val in files.iteritems():
 # R1 is run 1 from the file being read                                                                     
 if "R1" in key:
  for v in val:                             
   l1.append(float(v[0]))
   l2.append(float(v[1]))

 elif "R2" in key:
  for v in val:                             
   l3.append(float(v[0]))
   l4.append(float(v[1]))

 elif "R3" in key:
 for v in val:
  l5.append(float(v[0]))
  l6.append(float(v[1]))

 elif "R4" in key:
  for v in val:
   l7.append(float(v[0]))
   l8.append(float(v[1]))   

 elif "R5" in key:
 for v in val:
  l9.append(float(v[0]))
  l10.append(float(v[1]))

sum_val_0 = 0; avg_l_0 =[]; sum_val_1 = 0; avg_l_1 =[]


for val in zip(l1, l3, l5, l7, l9, l2, l4, l6, l8, l10):

    sum_val_0 = sum_val_0 + float(val[0])+float(val[1]) + float(val[2]) +float(val[3])+float(val[4])


    avg = sum_val_0/ len(val)

    avg_l_0.append(avg)

    sum_val_1 = sum_val_1 + float(val[5])+float(val[6]) + float(val[7]) +float(val[8])+float(val[9])
    avg_1 = sum_val_1/ 10
    avg_l_1.append(avg_1)



trace0 = go.Scatter(

 x = avg_l_0,

 y= avg_l_1,

 line = dict(
    color = ('rgb(205, 12, 24)'),
    width = 2)
)               

data = [trace0]
layout = go.Layout(

            dict(showlegend=True,
             xaxis = dict(title = 'Diameter', range = [35,1500]),

             yaxis = dict(title = 'Intensity', range = [-20,120], showline=True,),
          )
)


fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Comment: Please don't post your whole code here but create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not my whole code!

Comment: Maybe not. But it's also not a minimal example.